Как получить первые или последние N символов из строки в питоне?
Допустим, есть строка s, и нужно получить первые или последние N символов этой строки.
Как это можно осуществить в питоне?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Поищите про "срезы" в Python.

Вариант через срезы:
n = 'qwerty'
x = 2
first_chs = n[:x]
last_chs = n[-x:]

print(first_chs)  -->  qw
print(last_chs)   -->  ty

Про индексы и срезы - рекомендую к прочтению всю серию статей

спасибо, ваш ответ помог
